# ASP.NET MVC 3 View Engine does not recognise PartialView with .cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The below image shows the `Partial View GetMovieTypes.cshtml` living in the `Shared` folder

I call the partial view using the line `@Html.Partial("GetMovieTypes.cshtml")` in the Index View of EmployeeController

> **Issue is I get Server Error when I call the Employee Controller with Index Action**
>
> The partial view '_GetMovieTypes.cshtml' was not found or no view
>   engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:
>
> ~/Areas/Staff/Views/Employee/GetMovieTypes.cshtml.cshtml

But when I rename the `PartialView to GetMovieTypes.cshtml.cshtml` it works fine

***Why is the ViewEngine forcing me to add the .cshtml extension twice***

[image]

Comment: Dang just noticed my silly mistake immediately after posting this question, Cheers all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `.cshtml` portion:

```
@Html.Partial("GetMovieTypes")
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to call

```
@Html.Partial("GetMovieTypes")
```

*Dot* is not recognized as *extension* separator by `MVC` binding. So if you write

"GetMovieTypes.cshtml" it searches for *exactly* that name, **plus** `cshtml` extension.

Answer (score 2):

you should change your code call into

```
@Html.Partial("_GetMovieTypes")
```

as that's the name of your View, I do that all the time.

there is no need to mention the extension, that's only if you are calling from your `Controller`.

my own example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the .chtml extension:

```
@Html.Partial("GetMovieTypes")
```

You can also pass the model you havbe in the "parent" view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("GetMovieTypes", MovieTypesModel)
```

With this method, your view and its partial have the same model and information

*Maybe I'm wrong but I think you have an underscore in the name of the view too, so you should call it like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_GetMovieTypes", MovieTypesModel)
```